# Remove upload limit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, library, drag-and-drop

My task is to upload more than 100 items. For example, I select 200 items in a folder and drag to the library.

But I get an exception from SharePoint stating that there is a limit of 100 files that can be added at a time.

[image: Select item]

[image: Drop item]

I need to overcome this limitation, how can I do it?

Comment: can you translate the error in English?

Comment: Use Open with Explorer instead for this type of very extensive file transfers

Comment: Methods that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the limitation in SharePoint 2013 that you can’t upload more than 100 files one time using drag n Drop.

1. You can use [Open the Library in Explorer View](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-foundation-help/copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-open-with-explorer-HA101811182.aspx).
2. You can also [map library to a drive](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/can-i-map-a-document-library-as-a-mapped-drive.aspx) then upload the required documents.

Comment: Thank you, in my example is as follows: \\intranet.domain.com.br@SSL\DavWWWRoot\ti\XML

Comment: You may also want to mention that WebDAV has its own file size limit apart from the one in SharePoint at the web application level. The WebDAV size limit is changed in the local computer's registry.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer view can handle more than 100

1. On your SharePoint site go to the library you would like to add documents to.
2. Select “Open with Explorer” View.
3. Drag and drop your documents you want to upload to your SharePoint website.